# Bash - File local variables

Tags: prompt, bash, ps1

I just wrote a small file to set my PS1 variable. This file is sourced from my *.bashrc*. Now I have a couple of questions regarding this approach.

But first the code:

**setprompt**:

```
# Normal variables
BOLD="$(tput bold)"
RESET="$(tput sgr0)"

RED="$(tput setaf 1)"
GREEN="$(tput setaf 2)"
YELLOW="$(tput setaf 3)"
BLUE="$(tput setaf 4)"
PINK="$(tput setaf 5)"
CYAN="$(tput setaf 6)"
GRAY="$(tput setaf 7)"

# Make non-printable variables
PROMPT_BOLD="\[$BOLD\]"
PROMPT_RESET="\[$RESET\]"

PROMPT_RED="\[$RED\]"
PROMPT_GREEN="\[$GREEN\]"
PROMPT_YELLOW="\[$YELLOW\]"
PROMPT_BLUE="\[$BLUE\]"
PROMPT_PINK="\[$PINK\]"
PROMPT_CYAN="\[$CYAN\]"
PROMPT_GRAY="\[$GRAY\]"

# Other variables
USERNAME="\u"
FULL_HOSTNAME="\H"
SHORT_HOSTNAME="\h"
FULL_WORKING_DIR="\w"
BASE_WORKING_DIR="\W"

# Throw it together
FINAL="${PROMPT_RESET}${PROMPT_BOLD}${PROMPT_GREEN}"
FINAL+="${USERNAME}@${SHORT_HOSTNAME} "
FINAL+="${PROMPT_RED}${FULL_WORKING_DIR}\$ "
FINAL+="${PROMPT_RESET}"

# Export variable
export PS1="${FINAL}"
```

**.bashrc**:

```
..
source ~/.dotfiles/other/setprompt
..
```

**My questions:**

- Will this approach slow down my bash startup? Should I just write one ugly unreadable line of code instead of doing these variable definitions/sourcing?
- I noticed, that the variables defined in **setprompt** are still defined in my **.bashrc**. I don't like this behaviour since it's not obvious to the editor of **.bashrc** that variables are defined when sourcing **setprompt**. Is this just the behaviour of `source`? What can I do about this?

**Edit**:

This is the approach I use now (recommended by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)):

**getPrompt.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

getPrompt () {
  # Bold/Reset
  local PROMPT_BOLD="\[$(tput bold)\]" 
  local PROMPT_RESET="\[$(tput sgr0)\]" 

  # Colors
  local PROMPT_RED="\[$(tput setaf 1)\]"
  local PROMPT_GREEN="\[$(tput setaf 2)\]"

  # Miscellaneous
  local USERNAME="\u" local SHORT_HOSTNAME="\h"
  local FULL_WORKING_DIR="\w"

  # Print for later use
  printf "%s%s%s%s" "${PROMPT_RESET}${PROMPT_BOLD}${PROMPT_GREEN}" \
                    "${USERNAME}@${SHORT_HOSTNAME} " \
                    "${PROMPT_RED}${FULL_WORKING_DIR}\$ " \
                    "${PROMPT_RESET}"
}
```

**.bashrc**:

```
source ~/.dotfiles/bash/getPrompt.sh

PS1=$(getPrompt)
```

Comment: See: `help unset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping things human-readable is probably a good thing, and if performance is a problem, perhaps you can control whether this gets executed at all if your prompt is already set.  As a first step, maybe move the call to `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`.

You can either `unset` all the variables at the end of the script, or refactor the script so that it runs as a function, or as a separate script (i.e. call it instead of `source` it).

If you put it all in a function, the function will need to declare all the variables `local`.

If you run this as an external script, you will need to change it so that it *prints* the final value.  Then you can call it like

```
PS1=$(setprompt)
```

without any side effects.  (Perhaps you would want to do this with a function, too, just to keep it clean and modular.)

Comment: Having said that, the code has a bit too many indirections for my taste.  Putting `\[$GRAY\]` in a separate variable and then never using `GRAY` again seems like just unnecessary verbiage.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I declare a `local` variable just by adding the `local` keyword in front of the variable declaration (first time bash programmer here)? And what are the advantages of using `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Yeah, but it only makes sense inside a function declaration.

Comment: `.bash_profile` only gets called on interactive login, whereas `.bashrc` gets called for each subshell.  This is all documented in the manual, though different distros set up things slightly differently (for example, usually, `.bash_profile` will explicitly call `.bashrc` on login, but this is not necessarily universally true).

Comment: Thank you! I posted the code I use now. Maybe you could take a quick look for major flaws... I ended up sticking with the `.bashrc`, since my `.bash_profile` only sources my `.bashrc` and that's the place where I put all my enhancements.

Comment: If you are still concerned about performance, moving it to `.bash_profile` is still an option.  Your revised code looks fine, although posting it as part of the question is usually not recommended (post an answer of your own if you like).